# 64 digit Hex WiFi passphrase doesn't seem to get accepted

Tags: wi-fi, wep

I use a 64 digit hex passphrase on my router that I want to use with Android. However Android (CyanogenMod 7) doesn't seem to accept the password (no errors, just nothing happens when I enter it). I have also tried manually entering the information into the wpa_supplicant.conf file but to no avail.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why are you doing that? It sounds like a protected wifi network, and by peeling off the hex passphrase from a windows machine, you think you can get on the network. Is it your wifi network? If it is, surely you would have the passphrase. this sounds iffy?

Comment: Since the question was edited, what router is it in question? This is a case of a mis-configured router.

Comment: you should see the old revision by clicking on 'X mins|hours|days ago': http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/25259/revisions PS: I don't think it's a misconfig, more a typing problem with colons included or so.

Answer (score 1):

That has worked fine when I recently tested it with CyanogenMod 7 and 9 (and also stock HTC/Samsung/Motorola).

Just enter it into the usual passphrase input box but without any colons. Just type in only the 0-9,a-f letters. This should work then.

Here's a sample wpa_supplicant.conf entry with a fake key/AP:

```
network={
    ssid="insecureAP"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    auth_alg=OPEN SHARED
#   128 bit key:
    wep_key0=0123456789abcdef0123456789
#   64 bit key:
#   wep_key0=0123456789
    priority=90
}
```

Note: 64bit correspond to 10 hex digits and 128bit correspond to 26 hex digits (with WEP standard)!

Comment: TIL! Never knew you could do it that way... :D Nice... should be part of community wiki for the top gems /tips 'n' tricks for others to submit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:`auth_alg=OPEN SHARED` for this: `auth_alg=OPEN`

It just happened to me that my phone was trying Shared Key Authentication (SKA), which is seldom used in favour of Open Authentication.
By doing this my connection started working.